# Let $f(t)$ be a continuous function on an interval [a,b]. If $\int_a^b |f(t)| dt = 0$, then determine $f(t)$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f(t)$ be a continuous function on an interval [a,b]. If $\int_a^b |f(t)| dt = 0$, then determine $f(t)$.

Here comes my question. With such integrals including absolute values, I know that I can write the given integral as sum of two or more integrals according to the zeros of the function in absolute value. However, I don't know anything about $[a,b]$ if $a<0<b$.

Where should I start?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Why must the integral of a nonzero continuous function be nonzero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3426127)

Comment: Also related to [If $f\in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ satisfies $\int_a^b |f(x)|dx=0$ then $f=0$ almost everywhere.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2386968)